# Computed Vue Property with Getter & Setter won't compile in Webpack

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, computed-properties

I'm attempting to convert an app that was in development with just Javascript over to Typescript. I've ran into a problem I can't seem to solve. I have a computed property with a getter and a setter that won't compile when run through Webpack. I am not using the class decorator way of declaring components and am instead using the object literal syntax.

```
import Vue from "vue"

export default Vue.extend({
  computed: {
   prioritized: {
    get(): any[] {
     return this.$store.getters["blah"];
    }
    set(value): void {
     //set value here
    }
   }
  }
})
```

Below is the first error webpack gives me:

ERROR in ~listHome.ts(30,29)
      TS2339: Property '$store' does not exist on type '{ get(): any[]; set(value: unknown): void; }'.

I'm pretty new to Typescript to be honest, so I may be missing something simple here in my frustration of porting this app over.

Comment: are you adding store object inside the vue instance?

Comment: In the root Vue instance I do yes, and in other instances in this same component, specifically other computed properties, the $store reference works just fine. It's only on this one that has a getter and setter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wow, figured it out.

I was missing the type declaration for "value" and it broke everything. FUN

```
        get(): any[] {
            return this.$store.getters["homeList/sortedPriority"];
        },
        set(value:any): void {
            var test = 1;
        }
```

Comment: Good spot, thanks -- this got me for a while, and is obscure enough in what is actually causing the error to not easily come up in search results!

Comment: missing type declarations on a few getters were triggering this for me. You're not kidding about "...it broke everything".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `vue-property-decorator` you can do the following

```
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator"

@Component
export default class GetterSetterTest extends Vue {
  get prioritized() {
    return this.$store.getters["blah"];
  }
  set prioritized(value: any) {
     // set the value something like below
     this.$store.commit(.......)
  }
}
```